# Setting a Task Group variable in a script does not change its value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

How do I ensure a Task Group variable is updated and accessible in non-script tasks?

In a Task Group, after setting a `CONTAINER_PORT` variable in a script, it's available in later script tasks, but when accessing it via `$(CONTAINER_PORT)`, then the original task group variable value is returned.

e.g. After creating a build using the task group, I have to set the `CONTAINER_PORT` to `81` since all task group variables are required by default.

Task 1 - Configure Script (Bash)

```
containerPort=8080
if [ $(framework) == 'dotnet' ]; then containerPort=80; fi;
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONTAINER_PORT]$containerPort";
```

Task 2 - Generates Dockerfile (File Creator)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE $(CONTAINER_PORT)
...
```

Task 2 (Output) - I expect `EXPOSE 8080` here

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 81
...
```

Task 3 - Commit Script (Bash)

```
echo "Port should be set to: $CONTAINER_PORT"
```

Task 3 (Output)

```
Port should be set to: 8080
```

tldr; The correct `$CONTAINER_PORT` value is accessible in future script tasks, but not in the `File Creator` task which expects the file contents.

File Creator Example:
[image: File Creator]

Comment: FYI - Workaround is to require the `CONTAINER_PORT` as a build parameter instead of setting it using a script.

Comment: coming to the hard realisation that this is a limitation in task groups

Answer (score 0):

Your command string is missing a `;` and the agent is picky:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONTAINER_PORT]$containerPort";
```

should be:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONTAINER_PORT;]$containerPort";
                                                    ^
```